# python-dbus service process id

Tags: dbus-python

using *dbus-python* on Linux:

I can find out if there is a service provider:

```
   SERVICE = 'com.example.service'
   bus = dbus.SystemBus()
   print(bus.name_has_owner(SERVICE)
```

is there a way to get the process id of the provider of the server?